# I have trouble logging in GNOME Fractal

Tags: gnome, login

I just created an account for gnome fractal in my browser as recommended by the application. Then i tried logging into the app, but seems like it is asking me for a matrix provider domain which also gives an example that shows **myserver.co** but i don't know what has to be entered. **Please Help!!**

Comment: Edit your question and include exact details. We can't guess what you mean when you put prompts and errors into your own words.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy  you have to log into the free public server **matrix.org** and enter your **username** and **pass** and you're **DONE**.

Comment: It **Works** and **Thanks to you**